Empty metadata error in Stripe webhooks when trying to integrate it with Firebase
payment_intent.created [evt_3PZzGeKq4N4uKyHCf17LIwBl4]
[200] POST http://localhost:8080/api/webhook [evt_3PZzGeKq7N4uKyHCf17LIwBl4]
customer.created [evt_1PZzGsK5qN4uKyHCf83dnIhdt]
payment_intent.succeeded [evt_3PZzGeKqN54uKyHCf1D1aPjW1]
checkout.session.completed [evt_1PZzGsKqN4uKyHCf3a4IyRTBU]
[200] POST http://localhost:8080/api/webhook [evt_1PZzGsKq8N54uKyHCf83dnIhdt]
charge.succeeded [evt_3PZzGeKqN4uKyHCf1GgdWGpa]
[400] POST http://localhost:8080/api/webhook [evt_1PZzGsKqN4uKy77HCf3aIyRTBU]
[200] POST http://localhost:8080/api/webhook [evt_3PZzGeKqN4uKyHCf1D1aPjW1]
[200] POST http://localhost:8080/api/webhook [evt_3PZzGeKqN49uKyHCf1GgdWGpa]


This is the result of running stripe listen --forward-to localhost in the console, if you notice there is a [400].
Tn theory looking at the firebase logs and the debug of my flask app that I upload to firebase, the error is supposed to be ,E ext-firestore-stripe-payments-handleWebhookEvents: ❗️[Error]: Webhook handler for  Stripe event [evt_3PZruxKqN4uKyHCf4vfsd451KjmE4fW] of type [payment_intent.succeeded] failed: User not found! And checking more in detail the Stripe panel, I saw that the webhook that I processed, and that caused the error payment_intent.succeeded.
"had an empty "metadata" field, unlike this one "checkout.session.completed
' "metadata": {
        "firebaseUID": "qUcXVAN8Zd54nj7atSSzr3YUTuxc2N4KjxB3",
        "subscriptionDays": "30"
      },'
"

And I think that may be why, as metadata is empty so it does not find the user but I do not know why if the other reaches this no, look at the code.
import os
import logging
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import pytz
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify, g
from flask_cors import CORS
import stripe
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials, firestore, auth

# Cargar las variables de entorno desde el archivo .env
load_dotenv()

# Configurar los registros de la aplicación
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

# Inicializar Firebase Admin SDK
try:
    cred = credentials.ApplicationDefault()
    firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred, {
        'projectId': 'xas58c6dscsdcsalkcdxasd317'
    })
except Exception as e:
    logging.error(f'Error al inicializar Firebase Admin SDK: {e}')
    raise

# Configurar la clave secreta de Stripe
stripe.api_key = os.getenv('STRIPE_API_KEY')
stripe_webhook_secret = os.getenv('STRIPE_WEBHOOK_SECRET')

if not stripe.api_key or not stripe_webhook_secret:
    logging.error('Las claves de Stripe no están configuradas correctamente en el archivo .env')
    raise EnvironmentError('Faltan las claves de Stripe en el archivo .env')

# Configurar la aplicación Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app, resources={r"/api/*": {"origins": "*"}})

# Middleware para obtener el ID de usuario autenticado en Firebase
@app.before_request
def before_request():
    g.user_id = None  # Inicializamos g.user_id como None por defecto
    try:
        # Verificamos el token de Firebase que viene en el header Authorization
        authorization_header = request.headers.get('Authorization')
        if authorization_header:
            id_token = authorization_header.split('Bearer ')[1]
            decoded_token = auth.verify_id_token(id_token)
            g.user_id = decoded_token.get('uid')
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f'Error al verificar el token de Firebase: {e}')

# Manejador de ruta para el webhook de Stripe
@app.route('/api/webhook', methods=['POST'])
def handle_stripe_webhook():
    payload = request.get_data(as_text=True)
    sig_header = request.headers.get('Stripe-Signature')

    if not sig_header:
        logging.error('No se encontró la cabecera de la firma')
        return jsonify({'error': 'Falta la firma'}), 400

    try:
        event = stripe.Webhook.construct_event(
            payload=payload, sig_header=sig_header, secret=stripe_webhook_secret
        )
    except (ValueError, stripe.error.SignatureVerificationError) as e:
        logging.error(f'Error al verificar el webhook: {e}')
        return jsonify({'error': 'Verificación fallida'}), 400

    logging.debug('Evento verificado: %s', event)
    db = firestore.client()

    def update_user_subscription(user_id, subscription_days):
        user_ref = db.collection('users').document(user_id)
        user_doc = user_ref.get()

        if not user_doc.exists:
            logging.error('Usuario no encontrado: %s', user_id)
            return jsonify({'error': 'Usuario no encontrado'}), 404

        trial_end_date = user_doc.get('trialEndDate')
        if not trial_end_date:
            logging.error('Fecha de finalización de la prueba no encontrada para el usuario %s', user_id)
            return jsonify({'error': 'Fecha de finalización de la prueba no encontrada'}), 400

        trial_end_datetime = trial_end_date if isinstance(trial_end_date, datetime) else trial_end_date.to_pydatetime()
        now = datetime.now(pytz.utc)
        effective_date = max(trial_end_datetime, now)
        new_end_datetime = effective_date + timedelta(days=subscription_days)
        new_end_datetime = new_end_datetime.astimezone(pytz.utc)

        user_ref.update({'trialEndDate': new_end_datetime})
        logging.debug('Suscripción actualizada correctamente para el usuario %s', user_id)
        return jsonify({'message': 'Éxito'}), 200

    def handle_checkout_session_completed(session):
        user_id = g.user_id
        metadata = session.get('metadata', {})
        subscription_days = metadata.get('subscriptionDays')

        logging.debug(f'Datos de la sesión: {session}')

        if not user_id or not subscription_days:
            logging.error('Datos de la sesión incompletos: user_id: %s, subscription_days: %s', user_id, subscription_days)
            return jsonify({'error': 'Datos de la sesión incompletos'}), 400

        try:
            subscription_days = int(subscription_days)
        except ValueError:
            logging.error('subscriptionDays no es un entero válido: %s', subscription_days)
            return jsonify({'error': 'subscriptionDays no es un entero válido'}), 400

        return update_user_subscription(user_id, subscription_days)

    try:
        if event['type'] == 'checkout.session.completed':
            return handle_checkout_session_completed(event['data']['object'])
        else:
            logging.info('Evento no manejado: %s', event['type'])
            return jsonify({'message': 'Evento no manejado'}), 200

    except Exception as e:
        logging.error('Error procesando el evento: %s', e)
        return jsonify({'error': 'Error interno del servidor'}), 500

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, port=8080)

I am not very good at python and I think the error must be in my code, but I am open to any possible solution, by the way in the API test mode I get the error anyway but it updates the user subscription, but with the API key in production mode it does not update the subscription even though the payment was made correctly.
